# how to broadcast an event when my template is loaded?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

EDIT:it seems I messed things up, the directive is executed after the template is loaded anyway, I'll sort this out and edit my question when I have more time

I'm doing a conditional loading of templates/views with ui-router and then I want to apply a directive to modify the HTML of these template. I figured I would broadcast an event when the template is loaded and condition the directive onto this event. But can't get it to work.

This is how I load my templates:

```
FlatView.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("");

    $stateProvider
      .state('flatView', {
          url:"",

          views: {
              'main': {
                  controller:"flatViewElementList",
                  templateUrl:Routing.generate('_NRtworks_FlatView_elementList') 
              },
              'discrimSelector': {
                  controller:"flatViewElementList",
                  templateProvider:['BDParameters','$http','$rootScope',function(BDParameters,$http,$rootScope){

                    return BDParameters.then(function (result) {
                        //console.log(result);
                        if(result["selectorList"] === 0)
                        {
                            return "";
                        }
                        else
                        {                            
                            return $http.get(Routing.generate('_NRtworks_FlatView_DiscrimSelector')).then(function(result)
                            {
                                //console.log(result.data);
                                $rootScope.$broadcast("NRtworks_DiscrimSelect");
                                return result.data;
                            });                           
                        }
                    });

                    //return Routing.generate('_NRtworks_FlatView_DiscrimSelector');

                  }],
                    resolve:
                    {
                        test:function(BDParameters,$rootScope){
                            $rootScope.$broadcast("NRtworks_DiscrimSelect");
                          }
                    }
              }
          }
      });    
});
```

And this is the directive:

```
FlatView.directive('NRtworks_discrimSelect',function($rootScope){
    var linkFunction = function(scope, element, attributes)
    {       
        $scope.$on("NRtworks_DiscrimSelectLoaded", function(){
                    transformDiscrimSelect(element);
        });

        function transformDiscrimSelect(element)
        {
            console.log("occured");
            element.on('change',function(event){
                //do stuff
            });
        };

    };
    return{
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link:linkFunction
    };}
);
```

First, is the event system the right way to handle this ? If yes then what am I doing wrong ? If no, well, I'm open to suggestions ;)

Comment: the problem is here: `templates/views with ui-router and then I want to apply a directive to modify the HTML of these template` you don't apply directive to HTML, directives should be part of template so basically you are putting saddle on a pig ;)

Comment: are you sure that I shouldn't use a directive to add a js event for example on an HTML element ?

Comment: Directive has to be present on html when `$compile` runs (app bootstrapping, ng-include, directives) or you will have to compile it manually, you can't add directive element to DOM and expect it to work, from your description it looks like directive should have a logic to change the template conditionally not router

Comment: well I tried to time this because apparently when the directive runs, the template isn't loaded yet, so it's just not executed.

Comment: nope, it is.forget it sorry.

Comment: On the side note: when you define directive keep in mind that you can define link function and/or controller, link is executed post compile while controller is executed pre compile

Comment: before compil mean on the "raw" HTML before angular interprets its specific codes ? good to know